# Docker is not adding a network shared folder as a data volume

Tags: linux, docker

I have a **Ubuntu** host with a mounted network folder located at `/mnt/mynetworkshare`.

When I run my docker image, I want to expose the `/mnt/mynetworkshare` folder on my Ubuntu host so I run the container with the command:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /mnt/mynetworkshare/:/opt/shared_folder/ brspurri/my-app:latest /bin/bash
```

However, when I'm inside the bash shell of the container, the folder `/opt/shared_folder/` exists, but no files are present or visible.

When I change the host folder to a local one using:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /mnt/mylocalfolder/:/opt/shared_folder/ brspurri/my-app:latest /bin/bash
```

all the contents of `/mnt/mylocalfolder/` are visible and accessible in `/opt/shared_folder/`

*Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening?* **Is it possible to share a network folder with a Docker container?**

Comment: The short answer is that yes, what you are trying to do is possible.  WHat version of Ubuntu are you using? What version of Docker? Was `/mnt/mynetworkshare` mounted before or after starting the `docker` daemon?  Does restarting the `docker` daemon cause any change in behavior?

Comment: Thanks for your pointers. I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Docker 1.5. The network volume was mounted to the host previous to starting docker, and restarting docker doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: try adding --privileged docker run -it --rm -v --privileged /mnt/mylocalfolder/:/opt/shared_folder/ brspurri/my-app:latest /bin/bash I am actually mounting inside docker but to be able todo that you need the extra priviledges it may be the same for mounted.